# Checking for near-same IPs

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a problem where users are submitting more than one form with different ip's. (increment by one.) What I mean by this is that users are submitting forms using `123.123.123.123, then 123.123.123.124`, then `123.123.123.125`, etc. and so on. 

I've made a MySQL table that stores the IP and timestamp (UNIX) during the time of submission. How can I make it so that if there is an IP such as `123.123.123.123` in the table, a user with the IP `123.123.123.124` cannot submit the form within X minutes.

 So far, I've come up with iterating over the whole MySQL table, then checking if the IP's match somewhat. The problem with this is that there are a lot of records (`Roughly 25,000`), so I'd have to iterate through 25,000 entries every time someone submits a form, which is quite often.

Is there a better solution to use this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't store IP addresses as strings if you want to run queries on them later. Convert them to a proper numeric address using **[ip2long](http://php.net/ip2long)**

> ip2long — Converts a string containing an (IPv4) Internet Protocol dotted address into a proper address

For example

```
echo ip2long("123.123.123.123");     //2071690107
echo "\n";
echo ip2long("123.123.123.124");    //2071690108
```

Notice the pattern (1+)? Now you can easily compare the two and create an index on that value so your DB doesnt have to scan all the table.

Once you get the IP addresses to that format, you can write some simple math formulas to check the proper subnet range you are willing to check against.

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/223350)**

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 addresses can be represented as 32-bit integer numbers, MySQL can make the conversion using the function `INET_ATON()` or you can use the PHP function `ip2long()` to convert and compare if the IPs are inside a given range.